# C# skipping a part of my code

Tags: c#

Hey guys I've been trying to solve this problem for awhile now. I'm new to programming as I'm currently in my first session in College(Cegep). Visual Studio 2012 just seems to skip a part of my code where I need to enter 1 or 2 in *rehaussement = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());*
It doesn't prompt me to type something in. I've got no errors in the debugging section and here's my code: `

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //1464649 - Benjamin Lam
            int nbPhotos;
            char format;
            char reponse;
            char rehaussement;
            float prix;

            //Début

            Console.WriteLine("Entrez le nombre de photos que vous voulez développer :");
            nbPhotos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Quel format désirez-vous pour les photosÉ Entrez :");
            Console.WriteLine("p ou P pour petit format");
            Console.WriteLine("g ou G pour grand format");
            format = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            Console.WriteLine("Désirez-vous un rehaussement pour les photos? Entrez: ");
            Console.WriteLine("o ou O pour oui");
            Console.WriteLine("n ou N pour non");
            reponse = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());

            if ((reponse == 'o') || (reponse == 'O'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quel type de rehaussement désirez-vous? Entrez");
                Console.WriteLine("1 pour noir");
                Console.WriteLine("2 pour sepia");
                rehaussement = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            }
            else
            {
                rehaussement = '0';
            }
            //calcul du total a payer
            if (nbPhotos < 50)
            {
                if ((format == 'p') || (format == 'P'))
                {
                    prix = (nbPhotos * 0.15f);
                }
                else
                {
                    prix = (nbPhotos * 0.25f);
                }

                if (rehaussement == '1')
                {
                    prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.75f;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rehaussement == '2')
                    {
                        prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.50f;

                    }

                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (nbPhotos <= 100)
                {
                    if ((format == 'p') || (format == 'P'))
                    {
                        prix = nbPhotos * 0.10f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prix = nbPhotos * 0.20f;
                    }

                    if (rehaussement == '1')
                    {
                        prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.75f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (rehaussement == '2')
                        {
                            prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.50f;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((format == 'p') || (format == 'P'))
                    {
                        prix = nbPhotos * 0.08f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prix = nbPhotos * 0.16f;
                    }
                    if (rehaussement == '1')
                    {
                        prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.50f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (rehaussement == '2')
                        {
                            prix = prix + nbPhotos * 0.25f;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            //affichage de resultat

            Console.WriteLine("Le nombre de photos développées est " + nbPhotos);
            if ((format == 'p') || (format == 'P'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Le format choisi est PETIT");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Le format choisi est GRAND");
            }
            if (rehaussement == '1')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Le rehaussemenet choisi est NOIR et BLANC");
            }
            else
            {
                if (rehaussement == '2')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Le rehaussement choisi est SEPIA");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aucun rehaussement choisi");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Le prix à payer est" + prix + (" $"));
            //Fin
        }
    }
}
```

`
Most of my stuff is in french since I go to a french College(Cegep).
Would appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Have you tried `Console.ReadKey` instead?

Comment: I suspect that the line just above where you read 'reponse' from the console is not reading what you think it's reading.

Comment: @SteveG It should. `Read()` returns the int value of the character entered.

Comment: Yes, but the Console.Read() reads all characters, including the Enter key. I was trying to hint at the solutions below: use ReadLine().   ;-)

Comment: BTW you should get used to doing `int.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, and so on.  You'll catch bugs earlier by using the type-specific parsing functions.  For example, `int.Parse(Console.In)` is a useful compile error, but `Convert.ToInt32(Console.In)` will happily compile and then give a runtime error that's a lot harder to figure out.

Comment: @BenVoigt - `int.TryParse` would be even better :)

Comment: I just got into C# so I'm fairly new to this and just learn the basics like a week or 2 ago. I'll keep that in mind though, thanks!

Comment: @The3rdRefugee, if you're question is "solved" please mark an accepted answer.  Do not modify your original question to communicate that information.

Comment: Alright, just got onto this forum and not too familiar with it you know :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ReadLine() instead of Read():

```
format = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: And how will this solve the OP's problem?  In other words, what is the reason to use `ReadLine()` instead of `Read()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `format = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());` to use `ReadLine` instead.
The reason is due to the act that `.Read` doesn't end the input stream - as per msdn (see remarks section)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And how will this solve the OP's problem?  In other words, what is the reason to use `ReadLine()` instead of `Read()`?